# Having trouble destructuring user object from fetch response object

Tags: javascript, jsx

Currently working on a social media type app for class, but came across some issues grabbing values from user object.

friends is set to be an empty array. None of the other values destructered appear when passing the variable they are assigned too. want to know why the user is not getting set to data in the getUser function.

```
import {
    ManageAccountsOutlined,
    EditOutlined,
    LocationOnOutlined,
    WorkOutlineOutlined,
  } from "@mui/icons-material";
  import { Box, Typography, Divider, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
  import UserImage from "../../components/UserImage";
  import FlexBetween from "../../components/FlexBetween";
  import WidgetWrapper from "../../components/WidgetWrapper";
  import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
  
  const UserWidget = ({ userId, picturePath }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const { palette } = useTheme();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
    const dark = palette.neutral.dark;
    const medium = palette.neutral.medium;
    const main = palette.neutral.main;
  
    const getUser = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users/${userId}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data);
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      getUser();
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }
    
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      location,
      occupation,
      viewedProfile,
      impressions,
      friends
    } = user;
    
    return (
      <WidgetWrapper>
        {/* FIRST ROW */}
        <FlexBetween
          gap="0.5rem"
          pb="1.1rem"
          onClick={() => navigate(`/profile/${userId}`)}
        >
          <FlexBetween gap="1rem">
            <UserImage image={picturePath} />
            <Box>
              <Typography
                variant="h4"
                color={dark}
                fontWeight="500"
                sx={{
                  "&:hover": {
                    color: palette.primary.light,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                  },
                }}
              >
                {firstName} {lastName}
              </Typography>
              <Typography color={medium}>{friends.length} friends</Typography>
            </Box>
          </FlexBetween>
          <ManageAccountsOutlined />
        </FlexBetween>
  
        <Divider />
  
        {/* SECOND ROW */}
        <Box p="1rem 0">
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" gap="1rem" mb="0.5rem">
            <LocationOnOutlined fontSize="large" sx={{ color: main }} />
            <Typography color={medium}>{location}</Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" gap="1rem">
            <WorkOutlineOutlined fontSize="large" sx={{ color: main }} />
            <Typography color={medium}>{occupation}</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
  
        <Divider />
  
        {/* THIRD ROW */}
        <Box p="1rem 0">
          <FlexBetween mb="0.5rem">
            <Typography color={medium}>Who's viewed your profile</Typography>
            <Typography color={main} fontWeight="500">
              {viewedProfile}
            </Typography>
          </FlexBetween>
          <FlexBetween>
            <Typography color={medium}>Impressions of your post</Typography>
            <Typography color={main} fontWeight="500">
              {impressions}
            </Typography>
          </FlexBetween>
        </Box>
  
        <Divider />
  
        {/* FOURTH ROW */}
        <Box p="1rem 0">
          <Typography fontSize="1rem" color={main} fontWeight="500" mb="1rem">
            Social Profiles
          </Typography>
  
          <FlexBetween gap="1rem" mb="0.5rem">
            <FlexBetween gap="1rem">
              <img src="../assets/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
              <Box>
                <Typography color={main} fontWeight="500">
                  Twitter
                </Typography>
                <Typography color={medium}>Social Network</Typography>
              </Box>
            </FlexBetween>
            <EditOutlined sx={{ color: main }} />
          </FlexBetween>
  
          <FlexBetween gap="1rem">
            <FlexBetween gap="1rem">
              <img src="../assets/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" />
              <Box>
                <Typography color={main} fontWeight="500">
                  Linkedin
                </Typography>
                <Typography color={medium}>Network Platform</Typography>
              </Box>
            </FlexBetween>
            <EditOutlined sx={{ color: main }} />
          </FlexBetween>
        </Box>
      </WidgetWrapper>
    );
  };
  
  export default UserWidget;
```

Answer (score 0):

const {
firstName,
lastName,
location,
occupation,
viewedProfile,
impressions,
friends
} = user;

store all your data from fetch inside of useState

make it useState({your object})

Don't do this:

```
if (!user) {
      return null;
    }

const {
  firstName,
  lastName,
  location,
  occupation,
  viewedProfile,
  impressions,
  friends
} = user;
```

istead do:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});




const getUser = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users/${userId}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
    if(response.statuse===200){
          setUser(data);
    }else{console.log(response)}


    };
```

I am also working fetch in react. Do not forget to use

```
try{}

catch(err){
console.log(err)}
```

Comment: update function and received this response object in console.log Response

body: ReadableStream {locked: true}

bodyUsed: true

headers: Headers {append: function, delete: function, get: function, has: function, set: function, …}

ok: false

redirected: false

status: 404

statusText: "Not Found"

type: "cors"

url: "http://localhost:3001/users/63ec3e467d6d0f3f48b665c5"

Response Prototype

Comment: Did you correctly set up you Backend? Give your Discord/WhatsApp or Telegramm. I wanna check

Comment: ok discord username is SimonF#0636